# Can't open database file PDO Sqlite in the same directory

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

PDOException show that:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Just a line of, tried every option, works with absolute path only, but project will be moved on server, what to do?

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code here, not a picture of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the DB file is in the same directory as the php script you can use

```
$dbo = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."links.db");
```

The `__DIR__` magic constant will always have the absolute path of the currently running script which may be different than the current working directory. Overall it's good practice to use absolute paths.